# table structure to support multiple tries in to a single column

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, create-table

I am building a database to track photo sessions for a pet photo company.

I have built three tables, a client table with all related information about a client, a pet table to keep track of multiple pets per client.

The last table is where I am having issues.  It will have an entry for each photo session.  A photo session will have one client but could have multiple pets and may not be all of the pets owned by the client.

How can I structure the table to allow for this?

Comment: Have a 4th table that is a "many-to-many" mapping between `pet` and `photo_session`.

Comment: Thank you Rick.  This is exactly what I will do.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two tables: one to store the photos, and another for the many-to-many relationship between pets and photos.

```
-- you already have these two tables
create table clients (
    id int primary key,
    ...
);
create table pets (
    id int primary key,
    client_id int references clients(id),
    ...
);

-- create those
create table photo_sessions (
    id int primary key,
    client_id int references clients(id),
    ...
);
create table photo_sessions_pets (
    id int primary key,
    photo_session_id int references photo_session(id),
    pet_id int references pet(id)
);
```